# Tagging a question based on its answers

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Consider the following question:

> How do I use Frob to gurgle a flubber?

The OP has added [frob] and [flubber] tags to it. After a while, an answer is posted:

> Frob is not the right tool for the job. You should use Glub instead.

Suppose the answer is non-trivial, and that it is well-received. Is it okay to add the [glub] tag to the question?

Comment: This is an interesting discussion. However, I think the counterpoint of causing answers to be excluded needs to be viewed in light of some real context. Specifically, I have in mind the trend of nearly every javascript question being answered with jQuery. How does that factor into everyone's thoughts? If the OP doesn't specifically request non-jQuery answers, should it still be allowed? Or not done due to the probability that a plain JS answer would also work?

Comment: What about including tags relating to the Accepted answer. If the OP was asking for a way to "gurgle a flubber?" and then accepted an answer which detailed the use of a Glub, surely then the Glub tag can be added. The OP has provided confirmation that this solves their problem and people who search on the Glub tag, can now find this question and check if it is relevant to themselves.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In general, yes. Editing the tags, to add *or* remove, once an answer has been accepted is okay. If the answers make it clear that the problem in the question was caused by something other than what the asker thought, retagging is very helpful.*

[Removing inapplicable tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161415/159251) in particular is a good idea, to avoid dead-ends for future searchers, but [adding more tags that describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26914/159251) also helps the question to be found later.

Your specific example seems to go a little too far, however, because [as Bill the Lizard said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149347/159251):

> adding the tag exclude[s] other possible answers that don't include the subject of the tag

---

*Often some editing of the title and body is a good idea as well.

Comment: Let's see if I got it: if Frob is the only reasonable alternative to Glub it is okay to add [frob], and if the plan of the OP to use Glub was seriously misguided it might be appropriate to remove [glub] and edit the question title.

Comment: Yeah, more or less. If the question ends up _not being about_ Glub, you could remove [glub]. If I ask "Why is Glub snarfing my pibbers?" and it turns out that I had no idea what I was talking about -- it was another component entirely -- the tag's not helpful. **BUT**. On the other hand, someone else might make the same mistake and think that Glub is responsible. Depends on the situation; expert judgement necessary; your mileage may vary, etc.

Comment: On the other hand, suggesting a completely different tool makes for a less strong case for retagging. E.g., "How do I use regex to parse this?" and the answer is "Use PLY instead", I'd say _don't_ add [ply].

Comment: This is why it's helpful to use real examples when asking these questions, @duplode... Note how much shorter and clearer Josh's second comment was?

Comment: Yeah, @Shog9, I got halfway through the second rewrite of another "Flub" version and punted. But of course, real examples turn into analogies pretty quickly, which has its own problems: is "regex" to "PLY" as "`list`" is to "NumPy array"?

Comment: @Shog9 Indeed. FWIW, my question was inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276048 . It is still open; the OP hasn't make it clear why they thought lenses might help, and I wouldn't completely rule out a lens-based solution yet. All in all, a borderline case.

Comment: Found this looking for a good position on answering questions tagged with one means (`regex`) with other means (string / array manipulation).  Wondering - if a question is tagged `php` and `regex`, OP includes a regex example, should answers try and provide `regex`  solutions, or is it an open playing field?  Example question / answer (I was commenting on the answer being non-regex, and was not well received): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276098/870729 - also, if there's a meta post on this that is more relevant, would love to see it...