# Handling disagreement on tags

Tags: discussion, tags

A certain user [is adding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2682142/laszlo-papp?tab=activity&sort=revisions) is adding the [qt-signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-signals) tag to many questions to which it does not apply:

1. [Interesting task of the processes in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663191/interesting-task-of-the-processes-in-qt)
2. [Using multiple Ui's and Ui classes in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593484/using-multiple-uis-and-ui-classes-in-qt)
3. [Q_ENUMS are "undefined" in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066822/q-enums-are-undefined-in-qml)
4. [Referring to a predefined QMediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469798/referring-to-a-predefined-qmediaplayer)
5. [No matching function to call - compiler says I call (QObject *&) when call is (QObject *)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197572/no-matching-function-to-call-compiler-says-i-call-qobject-when-call-is-q)
6. [QLocalServer won't start an incoming connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394278/qlocalserver-wont-start-an-incoming-connection)
7. [Trouble in reading from Serial port using QSerialPort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644898/trouble-in-reading-from-serial-port-using-qserialport)
8. [What is the significance of Q_PROPERTY in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965777/what-is-the-significance-of-q-property-in-qt)
9. [Qt client - connect to C server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067451/qt-client-connect-to-c-server)
10. [QT NetworkAccessManager Unknown Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009234/qt-networkaccessmanager-unknown-error)
11. [Show another ui file on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473072/show-another-ui-file-on-button-click)
12. [How to detect Windows shutdown or logoff in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195935/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff-in-qt)

None of these are *about* the signals and slots mechanism in Qt, and few of them even mention signals or slots at all.

I think questions like these are examples of where the tag is appropriate:

1. [Are signals and slots syntactic sugar or there is more to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185946/are-signals-and-slots-syntactic-sugar-or-there-is-more-to-them)
2. [Using Signals/Slots to avoid circular dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030311/using-signals-slots-to-avoid-circular-dependencies)
3. [Qt: Return value of signal works, why is the official doc saying it is impossible / forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890644/qt-return-value-of-signal-works-why-is-the-official-doc-saying-it-is-impossibl)

Feeling the tag was inappropriate, I removed it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663191/interesting-task-of-the-processes-in-qt). He added it back saying "please do not remove important tags" and "you do realize that the solution as well as the question is primarily about qt signals and slots".

I find two issues with this:

1. The question is definitely **not** *about* signals and slots. It is about QProcess and how to accomplish something with it. The fact that the answer happens to involve signals and slots is incidental. If every Qt post where the question or answer happens to mention "signal" or "slot" were to be tagged this way, the tag would be diluted.
2. Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, tags are specifically for question content, not answers.

How do we resolve this without getting into an edit war?

Comment: Yes, I **really** am saying it is an inappropriate tag for that question.

Comment: There is not necessarily a problem with adding tags to a question based on a correct/accepted answer. In many cases it can even be helpful.

Comment: is this devolving into the "should we tag based on question, or based on answers"? If so, this is a duplicate...

Comment: Relevant if not duplicated: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers

Comment: @Bart / JanDvorak - I am not as concerned about the general idea of tags relating to answers. I feel that this particular tag is being over-used. As I said, I think tagging every question where signals and slots happen to be involved will dilute it. It would be like tagging every C++ question where a vector was involved with the the "templates" tag, even when the question wasn't *about* templates.

Comment: You're appealing to authority and conducting ad hominem attacks instead of discussing the issue.

Comment: I have noticed that, and I disagree that it would be destructive. I think there are plenty of questions with the qt tag that don't need it because it's not related to the issue.

Comment: I agree that there aren't very many questions with the tag in absolute terms (only 116 currently), but percentage-wise the proportion that don't belong is significant: 12/116 is over 10%.

Comment: It is your proportion without knowing much about the handling of it and without careful reading of the questions. I am not saying this negatively, just factually. You claimed they do not even "mention" signal and slot, whereas they have explicit qt signal handlers in there. I mean, really, I cannot follow you. You are now telling in comments to tag questions **only** with tags based on the actual problem, i.e. answer. Then, you started complaining about that in the beginning. I am honestly lost. I think you are hurt that someone pointed out that it was not a good idea to remove those tags.

Answer (score 7):

Start a meta question in which you discuss how the given tags should be used.  Let the community come to a consensus.  Link any users involved in the editing to the meta question so they can make their voice heard.

If, after a consensus is reached, edits continue to be made in violation of that consensus, then flag for moderator attention, and let them handle the situation.

Comment: I know you're answering the question, but aren't we kinda already discussing the Meta discussion you propose? ;)

Comment: @Bart I dislike the fact that so many meta questions asking about the process end up ignoring the process question and discussing the example.  If he wants to discuss this tagging issue, by all means, he should.  Trying to do both in the same question is just...messy.

Comment: Yeah, also, he did not quite stay civil with his question as the "common consensus" on meta (hint: writing the question partially against a user rather than completely the issue).

Comment: I know @Servy. I don't blame you for it.

Comment: I cannot understand how this post got upvoted so much. Is the voting really objective or I am missing something? I mean, this is the meta for stackoverflow, and the OP is trying to discuss the issue, and you are telling him to go to meta and discuss the issue, and then accept it. It is out-of-order even as a comment IMHO.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I disagree, the OP clearly asked: `How do we resolve this without getting into an edit war?` *What do I do about this?*. The question isn't directly dealing with whether the tags were appropriate or not.

Comment: @Seth: you seem to have ignored the OP. I will repaste it ...  `I would say my root question is "is this tag being used correctly".` But let us assume that the OP wrote what you think: Meta is still the place for discussing issues (even if crappy one, usually newcomers coming here complaining rather than learning), and this is the meta. The OP is at the right place to discuss this issue how to handle the situation at hand, IMHO, and he is rightfully hoping for real answers, not like this.