# Tagging answers?

Tags: feature-request, tags, duplicate-questions, answers

After having read this: "*[Tagging a question based on its answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252079/694576)*" it came to my mind that it might be helpful to tag answers.

This would help grouping questions (my marking them as duplicates for example) that came up with various ideas why something might not work, which in fact all reduce the same common problem, thus all having similar answers.

Would introducing tags to answers be an option?

---

**Update (to explain my thoughts behind)**

There sure is an implicit relation from answers to their question, by just being the question's answer.

However this relation is not (always) obvious from the question's tags.

- Lets have a set of questions all tagged differently.
- Let's further assume all those question can by answered by the the same answer (A).

How to find those questions, by just knowing the answer to one of them?

One approach could be to re-tag the question depending on the answer (as proposed by the link I quoted above).

But let's assume further those questions could be also answered by another answer (B) and this answer (B) would mutally exclude answer A it might have not been a good idea to tag those questions using a tag related to A, as this might keep the alternative answers (B) from comming.

Comment: 99.9% of every new post I see that's a dupe gets closed in like <3 mins, so introducing this new tagging system purely for dupe hunting (personally I think) seems unnecessary.

Comment: "*99.9% of every new post I see that's a dupe gets closed in like <3 mins*" I do not know which your favorite tags are. For the tags I'm active in 99% definitly is **not** the case. @Sam

Comment: I mainly talking about the C# tag. I see a dupe; flag it, a few mins later it's closed. I'm just saying from my own experience that the current system (for the tags I browse anyway) seems efficient enough. Still I guess [Kaizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen) is always a good thing.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer. @Sam

Comment: So to check I've understood, for example, "How do I download content programatically?" and "How do I make API calls?". Both answers would involve Curl, so you'd want to tag them both with curl. Then you could find any questions for which Curl was the answer. Right? But I don't really understand why - can you give a practical example in which you'd want to use that functionality?

Comment: I'd tag my answer to your comment's1st (example) question: [download] [curl] [c] and to the 2nd: [api] [curl] [c]. My approach assumes detailed tagging of answers (which might very well be possible, assuming the answerers know what they are talking about), typically using **more** detailed tagging, which might imply different tagging also,  then the question the answer answers. @Blowski

Comment: @alk I agree that it would add structured data to the answer, but I don't see a use case in which I would take advantage of it. If someone tags their question with curl it makes it more likely their question will be answered, because it puts the question about curl in front of people who say they know about and are willing to answer questions on curl. So it helps askers and answerers to find each other. I don't see a use case like that for tagged answers.

Comment: The advantage would be given if the "quality" of the answer is significantly higher then the "quality" of the question. For example in terms of details about a probably complex issue the question brings up even without the questioner being aware of, the questioner doesn't even having an idea about, but the responder obviously has. @Blowski

Answer (score 5):

I accept I **didn't fully** understand your question.

But we *already* assume that an answer ***is*** based on the tags in the question. If it isn't, you know what happens to it after being downvoted by the community.

So, tagging answers are redundant and even worse, it clutters the UI.