# I answered an old CSS question with a modern CSS3 solution. My answer now has over 400 votes. Can I add the CSS3 tag to the question?

Tags: discussion, tags, old-questions

This question, tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) was asked back in 2009: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1575141/1317805).

In early 2013 I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/1317805) which offers a modern [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) solution, which didn't exist when that question was first asked, which has now amassed over 400 positive votes and has overtaken all the other answers which had previously been submitted to that question.

I have a *total score* of 246 in the CSS3 tag, but because of this answer that really isn't an accurate representation of my understanding of it (not to sound corny...). With this answer included my total score for CSS3 would currently be 672 - almost 3 times higher than what it currently is.

Am I allowed to edit the question to include the CSS3 tag, or would that be detrimental to the other answers which have already been given?

On that note, should I be submitting CSS3 answers to questions which are only tagged with CSS and *not* CSS3?

Comment: Your answer uses css3, but the question doesn't ask specifically for a css3 solution or subject, so changing that to boost your own rep seems like a bad idea to me. On the other hand, this might be a good example of why answers should maybe be able to add tags of their own. Just my two cents.

Comment: @yuvi that's the problem. This question was asked before many CSS3 functions had really been implemented in any browser. The CSS tag is a bit obscure as if this question had been asked again but with the CSS3 tag present it would have most likely been closed as a duplicate of this question anyway. Obviously it would be a bit selfish of me to add the CSS3 tag in if my answer wasn't very popular, but because it's the most up voted answer it could be seen as the answer the people who end up there are looking for.

Comment: I think it should be retagged. Often answers are going to be more relevant than questions. For example, you mark a question as a duplicate if the *answers* are relevant, not the question. In that case, it would make sense to edit the question to match the answer so that future visitors don't pass by the question.

Comment: Closely related: [Tagging a question based on its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252079)

Answer (score 36):

Answering a question that is tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) should imply that any CSS version/level is accepted. CSS is still CSS regardless of version/level. With that said you should state in your answer from which version onward the feature is available and the *browser support* (I mean browser support is pretty much all that matters).

Adding the [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) tag won't invalidate* the answers but it also won't add anything useful to the question. Nothing will stop you from doing it (unless meta effect kicks in) and it's not necessarily wrong but it might confuse further people who want to answer.

If someone will add an answer for each CSS version, there is no real need to also add the tag.

---

*The [tag wiki for css3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css3/info) says

> Although CSS3 is still under development, many features are supported
>   by major browsers, and since most CSS2 properties and techniques are
>   still present in CSS3, questions regarding previous levels (CSS2.1,
>   CSS1) are still appropriate and encouraged.

---

On a side note that question could use some [more jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) to set the height. Should I tag it as such for those few answers using JS?

Comment: By that logic, shouldn't CSS3 be a tag synonym of CSS, just as CSS2 and CSS2.1 already are?

Comment: Yes and no because unlike those two, CSS3 still has modules that are under development or not fully implemented by all browsers. There seems to be a small problem here.. By following the tag wikis, CSS tag should accept any CSS related answers. CSS3 tag however should imply that the user wants a more specific answer, has problems with some new CSS3 feature implementation or just adds all CSS tags to make sure people get the point.

Comment: That's true, but you could reverse the logic and say the same about a question which is having problems with a CSS2.1 implementation that cannot use a CSS3 solution (on older browsers, for instance). As there is no CSS2.1 tag, the user has to explicitly state in their question that CSS3 cannot be used. CSS3-specific functionality isn't necessarily the best  solution to problems tagged with CSS3, and it should be clear from the question itself if a user is talking about a CSS3-specific function (CSS Media Queries, for example).

Comment: Yeah, that's the *small* problem with the current tags. On the other hand if the OP wants the question answered correctly then all the necessary information (including limitations) should be given in the question. Tags alone can never fully define a question and if the question is not clear then it should be closed >:D

Comment: This answer has lead me to create another question here on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276214/separate-the-css2-1-tag-from-css, if you're interested.

Comment: Also your logic of answering a JavaScript-tagged question with a jQuery solution is flawed in that jQuery is a third-party library. That would be a good example if my answer was SCSS, SASS or LESS, but it isn't, it's simply part of a more recent revision of the CSS specification. That's why I haven't accepted this answer, as thanks to the way the current CSS and CSS3 tags work I don't feel your answer fully applies.

Comment: Ah the jQuery part was just a joke, you can ignore that (only mentioned since some answers suggested to use JS). But I agree that the tags are not optimal and also don't have a clear use-case. That needs to change although changing the CSS tag now will require a lot of work since it has over 200k questions. And since it's a discussion it'll be great to hear more opinions on this.

Answer (score 14):

It's all about the question. If I had posted a C# answer, would that justify the C# tag in the question? No.

I know CSS and CSS3 are related tags, and sometimes someone asks a solution for a specific version of CSS, or any framework. In this case, the CSS3 tag isn't requested by OP, and the question is perfectly valid and fine without it.

Adding the CSS3 tag will invalidate all other answers that use a version before CSS3.

Therefore, no, don't re-tag it.

Comment: CSS 2 is backwards compatible with CSS 3.

Comment: So code written on CSS3 will always work on CSS2?

Comment: No, other way around. CSS 2 code will work with CSS 3.

Comment: So OP wants to change the question from CSS in general to CSS3 specific. Therefore all answers with release before CSS3 are 'not answering the question'.

Comment: The other answers are *also* valid CSS3. The OP's answer is CSS3 only, while the others also work in CSS2. Adding the tag wouldn't invalidate those answers.

Comment: @Scimonster: Well, someone could comment to other answerers: 'you are using old, outdated methods. You shouldn't use X for reason Y since Z is better.'.

Comment: There's still nothing wrong with those answers. They just aren't taking advantage of technology that came out after they were written.

Comment: @Patrick I don't think that's the same thing. Idioms in older versions of CSS may become invalid in CSS3, but that doesn't mean that a CSS2 answer should be rewritten (unless it's considered obsolete by CSS2 standards.)

Comment: @remyabel: And what if the future brings CSS4, 5 or 6 and those methods do become obsolete?

Comment: "...someone could comment to other answerers: 'you are using old, outdated methods." - You could do that anyway, without the CSS3 tag being present, as the current solutions are outdated in modern CSS. Adding the CSS3 tag will not invalidate the other answers, as the other answers all work the same way as they did back in 2009 on all modern browsers which support the CSS3 answer I gave.

Comment: The other commenters on this answer seem to have assumed that you want to `replace` the tag while you suggested to `include` it, which, I assume you want to add it. Replacing the tag would invalidate the answers if they don't work with CSS3.If they do, I don't see a problem.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, definitely YES, add a new tag!

SO posts are not for the questioner only, they are purposed to serve *future visitors* as well.

Judging by the views of the question, it has been a good search result during years. This means, that most likely it is a result of many searches even today. In 2014 I'd expect almost all coders/designers are using CSS3, why not offer them one more keyword?

Comment: @YouWhoDisagree SO is not an archive of questions/answers. It is expected, that the information provided in answers is up to date. The updated information is easier to find, when the question is updated too.