# Separate the CSS2.1 tag from CSS

Tags: discussion, support, status-declined, tags, tag-synonym-process

First off, I'm tagging this as a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) to gather other people's views on the matter. I imagine this question will be highly down-voted by users who ignore to read past this first paragraph, but please bear with me here.

I'm asking this as a follow up to my earlier question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276189/1317805), which asks whether it's okay to add the CSS3 tag to a CSS question from several years ago which has a highest-voted CSS3 answer.

#### Why is CSS3 not a tag synonym of CSS?

A few months ago the user cVplZ asked this question here on Meta: [Can we please make [css3] a synonym of [css]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/can-we-please-make-css3-a-synonym-of-css) This question was majority-downvoted with the reasoning that because CSS3 introduces new concepts which weren't present in CSS2.1 (or lower) these should be separated. Makes sense, but this seems to go against how most other tags work on StackOverflow. After all, [html4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html4) isn't a synonym of [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), and conversely [php5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5) is a tag synonym of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) whereas [php4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php4) isn't.

#### What's the problem?

The problem is that this works both ways. As an example, Internet Explorer 7 as far as I'm aware does not support any of the features introduced by CSS3. You could argue that Internet Explorer 7 was released so long ago now that it no longer matters, but unfortunately this isn't the case. Since the start of the year Internet Explorer 7 has popped up in at least 5,000 questions and answers on StackOverflow (based on the IE7 tag and searches for IE7, "IE 7" and "Internet Explorer 7") - and this is one browser alone. Internet Explorer 8 also doesn't support a large number of CSS3 features, neither do several other still-popular browsers.

#### Why is this a problem?

It's a problem because questions featuring CSS in non-CSS3-supporting browsers must explicitly state that CSS3-related answers are *not* desired, as [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) is a tag synonym of CSS. In my mind, this goes completely against the purpose of tags in the first place. As it currently stands, 61.1% of the questions tagged [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) on StackOverflow also feature the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag. In the 3 months since cVplZ proposed the tag synonymity of the CSS3 and CSS, 69.8% of CSS3 questions have also had the CSS tag.

#### How can we fix this?

If we're to continue to separate the CSS3 tag from the CSS tag we should also separate the CSS2.1 tag to conform to what tagging is all about. If I want to ask a question about CSS2.1 I should be able to do so without having to state *please don't provide CSS3 answers* within my question.

---

Finally, it should be pretty obvious that a question is talking about CSS3 anyway. You don't go into a question titled *Need Help with CSS Media Queries* and proceed to attempt to provide a non-CSS3 solution (which is largely the reason that most CSS3-specific questions do not feature the CSS3 tag at all). Although I guess this is more of an argument *for* the synonymity of the CSS3 tag rather than the removal of synonymity of the CSS2.1 tag.

---

#### Update

As mentioned by Spokey his comment on this post, [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) currently has several CSS3 tag synonyms associated with it. I've highlighted the CSS3-specific tags in red. Here are the current synonyms:

[image: Current Synonyms]

And here are the currently-proposed synonyms:

[image: Suggested Synonyms]

The [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) tag itself currently has no synonyms at all. This is quite a mess...

---

*I've down-voted the two CSS3 proposed synonyms and also down-voted the [css-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-content) synonym here because that was heavily modified in CSS3 and I feel should be a separate tag if we're to still keep the CSS3 tag separate.*

---

#### Update 2

Since there have been a lot of up votes and no answers thus far I'm adding the Support tag to this as well in the hope of attracting more views (especially that of an official moderator who would have the power to alter the synonyms if deemed a good idea).

---

#### Update 3

It would be really nice to get some official opinions on this. It's been over a month and people are still adding CSS3 features as CSS tag synonyms and CSS2.1 is still a synonym itself.

Comment: Also some CSS3 properties that were tags are set synonym to CSS instead of CSS3. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/synonyms

Comment: Which is why I prefer avoiding version specific tags altogether. I rather treat each one as separated product if it's necessary and not having a catch-all tag.

Comment: "If I want to ask a question about CSS2.1 I should be able to do so without having to state please don't provide CSS3 answers within my question." I disagree with this sentiment. **Even though** I agree with you that CSS2.1 tag should be separated from CSS tag. In fact, it would be good for all versioned tags to be separated from the subject tag. Long story short: I agree with u and still expect explicit mention of what answers NOT wanted. Unless you have anti tags. A tag that says NOT CSS3.

Comment: @KimStacks I do agree, but a version-specific tag of CSS2.1 *should* imply 'NOT CSS3' anyway. You shouldn't have to put that in the question - it's down to users to read the tags on a question before posting an answer, and it's ultimately down to the person who asked the question to decide whether to accept an irrelevant answer or not.

Comment: As the person who had proposed those 2 synonyms, have to say that my decision was influenced by the existing synonyms on CSS tag (and lack of them on CSS3). Unfortunately, I do not have a choice to remove them now. Would totally understand (and appreciate) further down-votes on them :) Personally, I think CSS tag should be for anything CSS whereas the version specific tags can be included only when needed (like use CSS2.1 tag when you don't want a CSS3 answer).

Comment: I agree, this is a mess. Separating the css2.1 tag is definitely the first thing that should happen. Also just want to point out how all those css3 specific tags, like css-box-shadow are prefixed with css instead of css3. Why? b.c most everyone refers to css3 as just css, b.c it is a synonym...Also, I can't even suggest any synonym of css3 and get error message "version specific synonyms can only be created by a moderator"

Comment: @cVplZ: I get the same error too. Maybe that is the reason why CSS3 has no synonyms and all CSS3 properties are added as synonyms under CSS tag.

Comment: I only just saw this question now. I asked for my old question [on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142591/should-css2-and-css2-1-be-synonyms) to be migrated here but it was deleted instead because it was deemed no longer relevant. I'll flag it again. Long story short, I merged [css2], [css2.1] and [css] because [css2.1] was *almost never used correctly*, but I did not make them synonyms for the same reasons stated here. The version tag is often used wrongly, but now that the merge has pretty much erased all past misuses of the tag, it shouldn't be difficult to correct future ones.

Comment: This too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129402/tag-synonym-request-css2-css

Comment: According to me CSS 2.1 shouldn't be separated, its just that CSS3 is a complete overhaul for CSS so take it as CSS for the base version and CSS3 for new ones, the only thing makes sense over here is to merge `box-shadow`, `box-sizing` like properties to CSS3 tag and not CSS tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always been of the opinion that [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) and [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) should be separated. I had a post asking if [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) (as in either the CSS level 2 standard in general, or specifically the 1998 recommendation) should be synonymized with [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) or vice versa, but I maintained that whichever version-specific tag was used, it should be kept separate from the generic tag. [casperOne agrees.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129402/tag-synonym-request-css2-css/129418#129418)

This was how I resolved it (from my previous post which has since been deleted):

> 1. Merged both [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) and [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) into [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) to normalize all misuses of the version-specific tags (e.g. in questions where the general tag would suffice)
> 2. Made [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) a synonym of [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) ([css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) remains distinct from [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) — I think the version is significant enough to keep around for questions specific to CSS2.1)
> 3. Manually retagged questions specific to CSS2.1 with [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1)

The current situation is that synonyms exist mapping [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) and [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) to [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) Both of these synonyms were established last year. The first one (with .1) is credited to another moderator, and since its creation only two users have ever attempted to use [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) to tag their questions. On the other hand, 25 attempts have been made to use [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2), with the most recent attempt being made just *a day ago*.

So it looks like the confusion lies strictly with the numbers 2 and 3 (i.e. most of the version tag misuse lies with [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) and [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)); those who refer to 2.1 generally understand what exactly it is about and know what they are doing.

I think it's OK to allow [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) to stand on its own for now. I have removed the synonym. Keep in mind that it will appear in autocomplete depending on what users enter into the tags field, and it may still end up getting misused. We'll just have to see. Note that [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) will still map to [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) accordingly, even in autocomplete.

[css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) is a whole different ballgame altogether. I'd rather not get into that just yet. Maybe another day.

Now for the rest:

- [css-border-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-border-image) [css-border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-border-radius) [css-box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-box-shadow) [css-text-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-text-overflow) [css-text-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-text-shadow) are introduced in various modules, but I don't think it's meaningful to have a tag for CSS Backgrounds and Borders, or CSS Text, or any of these individual properties. I have changed these to point to [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) instead.
- [css-background-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-background-size) [css-box-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-box-sizing) [css-calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-calc) [css-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-gradient) seem to have been merged into [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) while being made synonyms. I have removed the synonyms, but no questions exist with these tags. `calc()` is defined in the Units and Values module and gradients in the Image Values module, and I think these features are unique enough that they can have their own tags. I'm not inclined to take any further action right now until they resurface naturally, but if the other two reappear feel free to suggest them as synonyms of [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3).
- [css-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-columns) has an entire [module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol) of its own. I don't think it is appropriate to make it a synonym of any general CSS tag. I have removed the synonym.
- [css-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-content) also has a [module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-content) of its own (ignore the WD on www.w3.org, it is obsolete). I have removed the synonym suggestion.

On a related note, there was a [css3-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3-transitions) for a while, which I spotted and merged with the more widely-used [css-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transitions) some time ago. We don't really need to spend time figuring out whether a module tag should be prefixed with css- or css3-, because any part of CSS2.1 is going to be superseded by a CSS3 module eventually. Having a standard css- prefix has always worked and we can keep it that way.

Comment: @bjb568: On one hand, the OP did retag their question with the specific intention of attracting a response from a more esteemed user. On the other hand, I'm sure the OP is well aware of my prestige already. I'll leave it.

Comment: Heh, yeah, "official opinion". wat is official opinion. opinion is not official. The community decides.

Comment: @bjb568 by "official opinion" I meant the opinion of anyone with the ability  to alter the tags. Votes on posts are the community's input, but unfortunately the community [doesn't always decide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211/211113).

Comment: I'll accept this answer for now - thanks for your time. It would be nice to have the CSS3 tag looked over at some point though, so I may end up re-opening this in future if this picks up more attention.

Comment: @James Donnelly: I think CSS3 merits a separate discussion altogether, and definitely one to involve the community with.