# Alias tag synonyms [symfony2] and [symfony3] => [symfony]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The Symfony2 core team decided to close their mailing list to gather their support community on Stack Overflow: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-support-stack-overflow-as-the-main-medium

From their announcement, we can read:

> By the way, if someone can invert the symfony/symfony2 tag
>   relationship on Stack Overflow, that would be super helpful (symfony
>   should be the main tag and symfony2 just an alias).

I wanted to handle this.

I found the tag-synonyms page:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Also the way to suggest new synonyms for symfony2:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony2/synonyms

But I wasn't able to find where it was possible to edit them.

I probably don't have enough rep yet, so if somebody can handle this, that would be nice for the [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) community :-).

Comment: Well, they want to make SO their main support channel. They should clarify that's not for bug-reports and feature-requests, because we don't trade in those...

Comment: @Deduplicator bug-reports and feature-requests aren't community support topics, they are topics for the issue tracker. Symfony already has a very busy issue tracker, so suspect very few bug-reports/feature-requests on SO due to this decision.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I added a link to the [SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) in a comment to the announcement.

Comment: There is no alias between [c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [c#-5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0). Why should it be different with symfony and symfony2?

Comment: See [Separate the CSS2.1 tag from CSS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276214/2257664) for a similar question.

Comment: After consideration, I think SO should follow Symfony's name and use the *symfony* tag by default, and keep *symfony2* and *symfony3* only to questions specific to a version. Should we draw moderators attention to this question now that Symfony3 has been released and the official name is Symfony*?

Comment: @A.L if you have a way to draw moderator attention to this question, please do.

Comment: What's next? I've opened a new question, but even there no sign of a moderator. How can we draw their attention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged both [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) and [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) into [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony), leaving synonyms in place.

This means that all questions that were previously tagged with `symfony2` or `symfony3` are now tagged `symfony`.

Comment: again? are not the same things...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336357/2270041

Answer (score 13):

Given that Symfony 3 is now released last month and there are no *major* changes between Symfony 2 and 3, I think the alias should at least be removed (but I prefer to invert the alias, as proposed originally in this question).

Yes, [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) is very different from [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) and [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3), but please note that Symfony 1 reached [*end of maintenance & support* back in July 2012](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-1-4-end-of-maintenance-what-does-it-mean). There are very few questions in this tag.

Comment: Since there should be more or less the same number of users for Symfony 2 or 3, I don't think that aliases should be used. If I understand correctly, the alias would mark all the symfony questions as symfony2. Am I wrong?

Comment: @A.L. the current alias marks all `[symfony]` tagged questions as `[symfony2]` indeed. This alias should be removed (we all seem to agree on that). Whether a new alias should be introduced so that everything tagged with `[symfony2]` or `[symfony3]` should be replaced with a `[symfony]` tag is another discussion. Let's keep this focused, so we can remove this crazy tag alias as soon as possible.

Comment: I opened a chatroom in order to get feedback from some moderators: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110713/room-for-a-l-and-martijn-pieters

Comment: Here is a new question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322317/remove-aliases-between-symfony-and-symfony2

Answer (score 7):

[According to BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280311/2257664) it's ok to keep different and separated (without aliases) tags for different versions of a software:

> I have always been of the opinion that [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) and [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) should be separated. I had a post asking if [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) (as in either the CSS level 2 standard in general, or specifically the 1998 recommendation) should be synonymized with [css2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2.1) or vice versa, but I maintained that whichever version-specific tag was used, it should be kept separate from the generic tag. [casperOne agrees.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129402/tag-synonym-request-css2-css/129418#129418)

There is no alias between [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [c#-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0), but there is an alias from `php-5` to [`php`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/synonyms). So it seems that no consensus has been reached.

I think that the problem is the [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag, [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) and [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) are different softwares incompatible with each other. The [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag is ambiguous because the probability that a question tagged as [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) apply to both versions is very low. I see no reason to post a question with this tag instead of [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) or [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2).

I suggest to remove the [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag and keep only [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) and [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2).

Comment: but where would all the questions about Beethoven 5th go? [tag:symphony5]?

Comment: Well, there are no symfony1, symfony2 and symfony3 communities in the symfony ecosystem. It makes no sense to choose symfony2 as a reference where symfony3 is about ready to come out. Symfony tag is just the right way to get the whole symfony community in, whatever the version.

Comment: While there was a big difference between Symphony and Symfony 2, there is almost no difference between Symfony 2 and 3 (coming later this year). Besides this, some months ago, the Symfony core team decided to remove the "2" from its name and call it the Symfony Framework (instead of Symfony2 Framework)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo: symfony 2 and 3 are close but different because of some *backward compatibility* breaks, I agree that in this case *symfony* is the appropriate tag.

Comment: @WouterJ: I follow the Symfony blog but totally missed this announcement. Can you please provide a link? (searching *name* on Symfony's blog give me unrelated results).

Comment: @A.L at hasn't been officially announced, but here is the RFC/ticket about it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/4203

Comment: Yes in fact, the original question wasn't about inverting tags (that's non sense as both versions are unrelated) there were a wrong edit. But aliasing is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I would yet again like to bump this topic. More and more people are now starting to tag their question with both [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) and [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) if they're asking a general Symfony question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2%20symfony3?mode=all

Can we please remove the alias of [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony)?

Comment: I totally agree. Many questions tagged with symfony3 are related to symfony2 and the other way round. Is there another way to draw the attention to the moderators?

Comment: There are 3400 questions tagged with `Symfony3`. 1348 (!) are tagged with Symfony2 too.

Answer (score 2):

After consideration (and contrary to [my previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297777/2257664)), I think SO should follow Symfony's name, the number `2` was removed from the official name:

> hasn't been officially announced, but here is the RFC/ticket about it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/4203 – Wouter J [Jun 29 '15 at 9:43](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony/297777#comment213835_297777)

So the [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag should be used by default for Symfony questions, and [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) and [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) should be used if the question is specific to a version.

---

Contrary to the announcement and the title question, I don't think that the aliases should be created because the versions 2 or 3 of Symfony are used nowadays.