# Remove aliases between [symfony] and [symfony2]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

This is a follow-up of this previous question: [Alias tag synonyms [symfony2] and [symfony3] => [symfony]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297725/2257664).

Since the previous question didn't reached a consensus, I open a new question about removing the aliases. I think that inverting the aliases should be discussed in another question in order to discuss only one question at a time.

---

The situation is a little bit different from the time of the first question, the software was known as *Symfony2* and the developers decided to remove the number in the name and use only *Symfony* as the software's name:

> While there was a big difference between Symphony and Symfony 2, there is almost no difference between Symfony 2 and 3 (coming later this year). Besides this, some months ago, the Symfony core team decided to remove the "2" from its name and call it the Symfony Framework (instead of Symfony2 Framework) – Wouter J [Jun 26 '15 at 7:27](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony#comment211533_297777)

> It hasn't been officially announced, but here is the RFC/ticket about it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/4203 – Wouter J [Jun 29 '15 at 9:43](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony#comment211533_297777)

---

Nowadays, the [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag is a synonym of [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) and [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) is kept for questions about the older version which is not supported anymore.

So it's impossible to tag a question as [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) that would apply to the current versions [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) and [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3). It should be possible because even if there are Backward Compatibility breaks between the versions 2 and 3, most of the questions should be applicable to both versions.

That's why I think that we should remove the aliases between [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) and [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2).

Comment: @Braiam As noted in the question *Since the previous question didn't reached a consensus, I open a new question about removing the aliases.*. That's what I understood from this discussion: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30269234#30269234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synonym between [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) and [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) should be removed in order to end up with the following tags:

- [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) for questions about the now abandoned project
- [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) for questions about Symfony 2 or 3
- [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) for questions specific to Symfony 2
- [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) for questions specific to Symfony 3