# Remove aliases between [symfony2] and [symfony3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Recently I noticed that [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) is defined as an alias of [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2).

[image: Renamed]

IMHO they are not the same: Symfony 3 is the evolution of the Symfony 2 framework and is good to have different tags for it. Perhaps every version of the Symfony 2 have the tags as example [symfony-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.7), etc.

[Here](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-0-the-roadmap) is the roadmap of the Symfony 3 framework versioning.

And from this article about [What's new in Symfony 3?](https://www.quora.com/Whats-new-in-symfony-3):

> So what changed from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3? The legacy layer.
>   Symfony 2.8 is PHP 5.3 compatible and from 2.0 to 2.8, some parts of
>   the code have not been removed to avoid to introduced breaking
>   changes. If you application is using legacy code, you will get
>   deprecation notices. Symfony 3 is PHP 5.5.9+ compatible and and legacy
>   code has been removed.

The same decision is in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322320/2270041).

Comment: Based on that meta answer you link and the surrounding discussion you would say that at best symfony3 should be synonimized to symfony.

Comment: sorry @rene for my english, I only want to confirm [this accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322317/remove-aliases-between-symfony-and-symfony2/322320#322320) about the behaviour of the symfony tags

Comment: well, the vote distribution isn't clear. there are upvotes and downvotes. I'm not sure that is enough consensus to have a moderator take action unless more symfony tag followers chime in here. I'm not one of them so my opinion doesn't matter much

Comment: The point of versioned tags is the version. I was just frustrated by this very issue http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337548/tag-edit-doesnt-stick. If my problem is version specific, I definitely don't want my tag changed to another version. If synonymizing *must* be done (and I don't agree that it does), it should be to the base tag (e.g. 'symfony') rather than another version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has come up twice quite recently and causing confusion. The synonym is now removed - if there's *any* reason it shouldn't be that I'm missing - then comment below this answer and we can review it.

Comment: I prefer using this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297725/792066

Comment: What ^ said. See Wouter J's contributions. Even A.L is now in favor of not having two separate tags for Symfony2 and Symfony3.