# Symfony2 and Symfony3

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

While Symfony2 and Symfony3 are very similar, Symfony is a complete different (legacy) framework. There is no need to have Symfony2 and Symfony3 as two different tags. Everyone agrees: [Alias tag synonyms [symfony2] and [symfony3] => [symfony]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony)

There are currently 3412 question tagged with Symfony3 and 1355 of them are tagged with Symfony2 too. This is a bit annoying, but it's even worse to see when you consider the Documentation page are using those tags too. Many topics from Symfony2 are usable for Symfony3 and the other way round.

However, nothing has changed yet. Can someone please fix this problem?

Comment: How should questions related to the legacy Symfony framework be tagged? I do agree that moderators need to get more actively involved in these requests.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336357/remove-aliases-between-symfony2-and-symfony3?rq=1

Comment: @Stijn The legacy framework is very outdated and new question related to it are not to be expected.

Comment: I'm looking now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Any news?

Comment: @StephanVierkant: I duped this post, I recorded the outcome on the other post.