# Why does current Symfony tag redirect to legacy Symfony2 instead of current Symfony3?

Tags: support, tags

It's no secret that [Symfony uses SO for their support](https://symfony.com/support)

[image: screenshot of symfony support page]

They directly link to the [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag page, which doesn't exist, so it's automatically redirected to the [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) tag page.

Since the current version is 3.1, now we're seeing [a mess of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2+symfony3) tagged with both [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) and [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) seemingly just for popular visibility.

Since [we don't we have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony) just a plain-jane [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) tag, why aren't we at least redirecting to the current version instead of the legacy version?

Comment: See [Alias tag synonyms symfony2 and symfony3 => symfony](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony)