# Cannot add symfony3 tag on a question that already has symfony2 tag

Tags: support, tags, questions

On this question: [How to compile variable names using Symfony's ExpressionLanguage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289538/how-to-compile-variable-names-using-symfonys-expressionlanguage)

I've tried several times to add the [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) tag but it does not seem to work. Is there a bug or is this by design?

Comment: By design since `symfony2` is a synonym for `symfony3`.

Comment: @yellow, what's `[tag:symfony3]` syntax?  Is this something I can add or what is that?  where will it make a link?

Comment: That synonym has been in place since July 29th... I don't know the framework but is there any reason they should be synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) is one of the synonyms for [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) (the other one being [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony)). You can see this on the [tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony2/synonyms). Therefore, it doesn't matter which of the three tags you add to a question; you will always end up with the so-called 'master tag', [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2).

Comment: I wonder if this really should be the case though...

Comment: Yeah, me too. Somebody could open a Meta thread requesting synonym disassociation. Not me, I know nothing about Symfony.

Comment: Ummm... Looks like the rabbit hole starts with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327305/why-does-current-symfony-tag-redirect-to-legacy-symfony2-instead-of-current-symf?s=4|1.0840

Comment: mmm I don't know much about symfony either, so can't comment on whether or not they should be together or separate.  My desire to add the tag was due to thinking ... `symfony2` has the higher number next to it compared to `symfony3` so maybe I should add it as well to get those who follow the latest tag

Comment: @JonClements actually here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297725/792066

Comment: If there's not much difference between [symfony2] and [symfony3] (which seems to be case from @Braiam's link), I could understand why they're synonyms of [symfony]. But [symfony2] as master tag makes no sense.

Comment: @Glorfindel that was the point of using that link, it makes no sense to have several tags for the same thing, specially if the volume of new questions is low.