# tag edit doesn't stick

Tags: support, tags

I've been trying to edit the tag on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294293/extend-entitytype-set-choices-to-selected-entity-only/40452779#40452779) from symfony2 to symfony3. I've used the 'edit tags' method and also the 'edit post' method. In both cases, I delete the wrong tag, add the new tag and save. After the save, it's as though I did nothing: the tag is still symfony2.

Do I not have enough privileges to edit my own tags? If so, it would be good if a message popped up to say so.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337036/cannot-add-symfony3-tag-on-a-question-that-already-has-symfony2-tag/337037#337037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) was a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony2/synonyms) of [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2). The synonym [is now removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337550/1835379).

This meant that if you added [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) to your question, it was automatically replaced with [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2)

Comment: Do you happen to know why this was done? (The synonymizing, not the automatic replacement.)

Comment: @RadLexus: I do not.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336357/2675154

Comment: @honk: Good find. Very related, maybe even a duplicate since it's about the same synonym... Different question though.

Comment: Ok, that explains the issue. But synonymizing symfony3 to symfony2 was a bad call on someone's part. The point of versioned tags is that they are specific to the version. Otherwise, I'd just have used the symfony tag and skipped the version. @honk, thanks for the link. I'll go make my argument over there.

Comment: @dnagirl it's been removed - see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336357/remove-aliases-between-symfony2-and-symfony3