# Symfony tag replaced Symfony[version] tags: where are documentation and requests?

Tags: bug

Take a look at [Stack Overflow's Symfony documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/symfony/topics?tab=requests): it seems that old documentation and requests are gone after [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony).

Is there a way to check if I'm right and, in this case, restore all the things?