# Tags on answers

Tags: feature-request, tags, answers

Currently it's possible to have tags only on questions; answers have been deprived of this possibility. However, it is not uncommon for a slightly more general question to get answers that, constructively, go beyond the categories originally deemed relevant to the thread by the OP.

Consider [Writing Emacs extensions in languages other than Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187/writing-emacs-extensions-in-languages-other-than-lisp).

— the title is quite general, but the question body specifically talks about OCaml only. However, consider my answer to it, which addresses the OCaml part of the question but also answers the more general questiom title with references to Haskell and Scala. Now, it would be quite unnice to add a haskell or scala tag to the question, but the question undoubtedly bears high relevance and usefulness for an audience more general than just OCaml developers using Emacs. But as there are no haskell or scala tags on the question, it is less likely for these communities to stumble uppn and participate the thread.

Is there a particular justification for not adding ability to

1. either add tags to answers, or
2. add auxilliary/secondary tags to the original question?

Alternatively, should I just go ahead and amend the question tags? What if more relevant tags emerge from the answers?

Comment: related: (not a dup) [Tagging a question based on its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate (at least not of that one): this is a feature request; that one just asks if it's OK to add one more very specific tag to the question.

Comment: seriously? not a single explanation of why this question is bad? it's carefully written and thoughtful...

Comment: @ErikAllik Voting is different on meta. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: I wonder if there should be a big box with bold text popping up whenever someone goes to ask a question on meta that explains how voting is different here, because it seems what @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå just explained has to be repeated over and over again in comments.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå  I did not know this either. And the mousover-text on the voting buttons is contradictory to this perspective.

Comment: This makes total sense to me. For example in Excel there are multiple ways to address a problem. Sometime the OP wants a solution and tag excel, but the solution uses Power Query. That was not considered in the question. So it makes sense to tag the answer with the specific excel tool, without adding this tag to the question that didn’t require a specific approach. Tag is good for better classification and search, so the search engine can take into account tags that are in answers too.

Answer (score 4):

I would very much like to have tags on answers. Consider Swift, evolving quickly. Many questions that were originally asked were asked about swift but now Swift 3 is current and mostly different. Adding a [swift3] tag to an answer where the response specifically addresses (or provides code for) the Swift 3 version of the language would be very useful. Re-tagging the question with the later tag ([swift]->[swift3]) isn't really correct since the question refers to the original version of the language. Adding a new tag isn't always possible since the limit is 5.

Also useful would be the [obsolete] tag, able to be applied to answers that were once correct but are now recommending deprecated or otherwise outdated methods. Such answers would be made obvious to readers so that they would not attempt to apply these methods and would also not waste their own rep with downvotes.

We should keep the answers around for ever but it should be obvious when an answer no longer applies, or specifically *does* apply to a particular standard.

Comment: One not-awful thing about Docs is its applies-to-version-X boxes.  Porting those to Q&A has been suggested a couple of times.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, the fact that there could be more than five tags on this question, or that answers might have different tags from the question and each other, suggests that is insufficiently specific, and not a good fit for SO. Imagine there are three good answers in three different non-Lisp languages; which is *the* answer, and gets accepted?

Also, looking at the current answers (most of which amount to links to various off-site resources, and one of which *isn't an answer*), that question *really* doesn't make a strong argument for supporting a new feature.

It could possibly be [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic), but I certainly don't think that allowing separate tagging of answers is the way forward.

Comment: sometimes when someone asks a perfectly valid question there end up being multiple answers that use different libraries (or some that use no libraries).  Tags on answers might make it easier for users to find an answer that uses a particular library.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to see tags not for languages so much, as for meta-linguistic styles or schools of programming.  Some styles use variables, some use no variables.  Some styles are procedural, some are more functional, some are one-liners of nested functions or pipes or shells.

For example, [Remove all but latest version - no timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447850/remove-all-but-latest-version-no-timestamp/447907?noredirect=1#comment812673_447907) currently has two answers:

- [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447907/165517) is [**simple**](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/simple.html) and uses low-level **software tools**, (no `awk` or `sed`), it only solves the problem if the input data is similar to what the OP noted.
- [*Stéphane Chazelas's* answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447946/165517) is more complex and uses more powerful text processors, (`sed` and `awk`), it's also more **general** and [defensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), he solves the problem even for the worst case scenario of input data, (file names containing control characters, *etc*.).

It would be useful if there were tags that allowed programmers to more easily find answers in those styles they prefer or require.  Maybe it would also reduce dogmatism about mere stylistic disagreements -- sometimes styles of programming are reflexively downvoted not because something doesn't work, but because the downvoter prefers their own style.