# Subset of tags of question to be applied to its answers?

Tags: feature-request, tags, answers

I am asking here for tagging answers, but *not* the way another similar request [Tags on answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286607/5047996) does.

#### Introduction

Tripping over numerous quite general questions and tons of more specific respective answers (with respect to the tags of the question), the following idea came to my mind: having the possibility for each answer to (de-)select from the set of tags given by the original question (all selected as per default).

#### Fictitious Example

There is a question like:

> **Q:** How can I do this on that environment using one of those?  [*tagged* [tag-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-x) [tag-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-y) [tag-z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-z)]

And the related answers read:

> **A1:** Try these.
>
> **A2:** Do this.
>
> **A3:** Do that.
>
> **A4:** Or even such.

For some answers all of the original tags apply, but for some others not.

#### Feature Request

What about the possibility to deselect certain tags from the original set for each answer individually?

Returning to our above example the result could look like:

> **A1:** Try these.  [[tag-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-x) [tag-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-y) [tag-z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-z) *tagged as per default, all selected*]
>
> **A2:** Do this.  [[tag-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-x) [tag-z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-z) *a tag deselected*]
>
> **A3:** Do that.  [[tag-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-y) *only one tag kept (one is minimum)*]
>
> **A4:** Or even such.  [[tag-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-x) *also one tag remaining*]

#### Another Example

A more concrete example for a realistic question is:

> How can I achieve ... on a Windows environment with some native functionality?

#### Rationale/Conclusion

Assuming the above question is tagged [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-files) [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript), and supposing *you* are providing an answer that constitutes a pure [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution, I would appreciate the possibility of deselecting some tags for your answer and keep the only applicable ones, [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-files). Another person might contribute a hybrid [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)+[vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) answer and should therefore select the applicable tags as well.

The great advantage that I can see is in searching for answers to a specific issue. So if I am looking for a [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file)-related answer I want to find *your* solution but not that of the other person.

#### Amendment

I am *not* requesting a `tags` field like for questions where arbitrary tags could be defined (so for the above sample no new tags like [jscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscript) can be added). Rather it might be a list of tags as given in the original question with related checkboxes each, all of which are ticked as per default.

The selection by these checkboxes is in the same scope as every other data of the answer, meaning that it is part of the creation/edit frame (**Your Answer**/**Answer**) that contains the `Body` field.

Comment: If a question is asking for a solution in tag-a or tag-b or tag-c, it's probably going to be too broad.

Comment: We can hardly trust *askers* to tag their questions properly; the problem would multiply if answerers suddenly had to do the same thing. And the  benefit looks... questionable. There are almost ten million questions now on SO; would this be a massive improvement for a sizeable portion of them?

Comment: Let's say I wrote an answer in pure batch file. Marked it as such. Another guy/girl came and added second answer that gets my .BAT and calls it through a CMD+PS instead of just CMD and marks it with  bat+ps, just because OP mentioned Powershell. Anyways, why'd we want to explode the set of answers by the tag combination count? It's not "how do I do that in 99 languages" quiz, at least usually. Anyways, even if so, should the author be able to 'accept' multiple answers depending on answer tags? Why shouldn't I be able a new tag to answer - since I answer, maybe I know better tags than used?

Comment: @Pekka웃, almost 10 million questions now on so? That big banner-thing hasn't got through to you, has it?

Comment: This would be a much larger UX complication than you think it would, for very little benefit... if any.

Comment: @Bill well, almost 10 million that aren't *complete* garbage.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302932/187606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are for connecting answerers with questions they are able to answer, not for allowing an answer to specify which tag an answer might address.

To put it another way: those ads that you see when looking at a question -- they can be displayed based off of question tags. Let's say that I make a widget for the dev environment 'happyIDE' (Trademark pending.)  As an advertiser, I can ask that any questions tagged [happyide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/happyide) get preference for using my Stack Exchange advertising budget.

Answers have no bearing on that.. never have, and never will.