# Is the retag reject right?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, rejected-edits

I retagged [Overflow Errors in 64-bit Windows Server 2012 after Upgrade to .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880570/overflow-errors-in-64-bit-windows-server-2012-after-upgrade-to-net-framework/28881104), just added [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) and removed [windows-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012). This retag was rejected and after that [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) was removed and [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) was added by Greg Pettit.

It is said in the revision:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

But FAQ and some posts like [Tagging a question based on its answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers) says that tags should help to find posts and they can be based on the answer.

I think that [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) and [interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interop) describe the post better than [windows-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012) because the error can be reproduced on all 64 bit Windows and the problem more likely is how to properly import the function.

**So my questions are:**
Was my retag right?
What rule I shoould use to retag?

Comment: I would have left the windws-server-2012 tag on. It doesn't hurt...