# What tag should be relevant to the question

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I have written an answer to a question and added tags that I used to the question to support my answer. Someone edited the question and removed the tags. Is this a correct behavior?

After two times editing to return the tags I have flagged this question. Now this issue is on meta. What did I do wrong? Shouldn't tags relevant to my answer be added to the question ?

The question affected is: [How to display the time in 24-hour format using Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902122/how-to-display-the-time-in-24hours-format-using-struts2)

Comment: As per Robert Harvey on MSE: [Tags apply to the question, not the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125202/)

Comment: Yes, tags apply to the question, but be relevant to the question *and answer*, even if the answer is an accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Tagging a question based on its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers)

Comment: @AzizShaikh The tags were removed that I added to the question, not OP did it.

Answer (score 15):

As the comments on your question also indicate: the tags apply to the question, not the answer.

If the question is *"How can I do X"*, and the answer is *"You could do so by using library Y"*, `Y` is not a valid tag for the question.

---

Given the comment just posted six months later I'll try to elaborate with an example, as my answer apparently still might be viewed as unclear. Consider the following question:

> **Title**: Add a number to another number in JavaScript
>
> **Question**: I want to create a JavaScript program that adds the number 40 to the number 2. How can I do so?
>
> **Tags**: [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Then it's perfectly fine to add an answer like this:

> You can use the jQuery Math library. It works like this:
>
> ```
> var number1 = $.math.number("40");
> var number2 = $.math.number("2");
>
> var result = number1.add(number2);
> ```

This is a valid answer, because the language used is JavaScript, as indicated by the question's tags. **However**, given your answer adds an additional library, **the tag for that library applies to your answer only**. So you don't go and add the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag to the question, because that would invalidate existing answers, and prevent answers to be added that don't use jQuery.

Comment: Unless it was there before, in which case the answer is devoid of information, instead of (probably) just severely lacking. </nitpick>

Comment: @Deduplicator not sure what you mean by that. If the question is _"How can I do X with Y"_, then of course Y is a relevant tag.

Comment: I was not asking where the tags apply. I have also not asked which tag is valid or invalid for the question if such tag ever exists. I don't understand, is it a comment to my question?

Comment: @Roman my answer is an answer to your question. In it, I try to explain why you should not add tags to a question when those tags does not apply to the **question**.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've already told you, this is not answer to my question, even not close to it. If you'll try to make me your decision, I'm not going to challenge it. Stay at your opinion and do not bother me.

Comment: @Roman from your question: _"Shouldn't tags relevant to my answer be added to the question?"_ - **no**. There's your answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @CodeCaster The questions are always wrong, has errors, bugs, and wrong tags. On the other hand a good answer fixes it, why not to allow to add tags that are relevant to that post?

Comment: @Roman why are you asking the same question again six months later? You have my answer, deal with it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you remove this answer?

Comment: @Roman why do you want me to remove it?

Comment: This is wrong answer and should be deleted, I don't understand why it's upvoted. The SO allows to post wrong answers, but I don't want this answer on my question. I'm owner, and I want to manage it. Could you help?

Comment: @Roman I fail to see how my answer (summarized: _"no"_) doesn't answer your question (summarized: _"Should I add tags to a question where the tags only apply to my answer?"_). Maybe I'm just misunderstanding your question, but then with me eleven other users also do. Perhaps consider editing your question so it asks the question you actually want answered.

Comment: @CodeCaster You have posted example that should be closed as unclear question in 10 sec.

Comment: @Roman that doesn't change the facts about the tags.

Comment: @RomanYou asked for what the rules are on a specific topic, and got an answer - it's the correct answer (based on a broad community consensus) even if you don't like it.

Comment: Even if based on a broad community consensus, It doesn't work.

Comment: @Roman please elaborate on "doesn't work". The fact that, in the case of the above example, **you** want to add the `jQuery` tag does not make that valid or useful. Again, please edit your question to ask the question you actually want answered. This answer is and will remain the answer to the question you currently ask.

Comment: Doesn't work, means "it doesn't work". I need tags on the question because I manage these tags, why can't I add these tags to the post that I have answered?

Comment: @Roman because they apply to your answer only, not to the question or to other answers. I've ran out of ways to explain that to you, so thank you for this discussion, but this will have to do.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to explain me but it is more wrong because you stay on your opinion

Comment: What other answers are you talking, the only answer is that is marked as accepted.

Comment: The correct only answer to the question that is linked is to use jquery, so why I can't add jquery tag to the question? Can you explain me this? Or may be I need to add javascript?

Comment: Users upvoted and accepted the answer that is using jquery, but the question is missing jquery tag, is this correct?