# Is it OK to change question title to sort of reflect the answer?

Tags: discussion

In a question titled [How can I update the DOMs asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917058/how-can-i-update-the-doms-asynchronously#comment63298543_37917058), the poster wondered why the browser was blocking, and imagined it had to do with his use of `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. After more prodding than should have been necessary, he finally posted more code, at which point it became obvious that the root cause was a synchronous XMLHttpRequest call.

I am sorely tempted to edit the title to read something like "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest call blocks browser". My logic is that no-one would ever find this post searching on the original title. Is this sort of title editing recommended, or OK, or to be avoided?

Comment: I do not believe this is an appropriate edit at all.  As far as searching, it seems that Google (among others) is smart enough to find relevant information even when titles are ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't edit the answer into the title :/

Comment: Seems similar to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318608/is-it-good-practice-to-update-a-questions-tags-based-on-the-answers

Comment: Also see [Should a post title be modified to fit the problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278431) Please do improve that title.