# Adding tags to a question that are relevant to the answer proposed

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I found a lot of questions/answers dealing with adding/removing tags that may be irrelevant to the questions but I usually face some situations where I am in doubt about adding more tags that may be relevant or not with the initial question.

Let me explain with an easy situation:

> A user is asking a question tagged with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) trying to
>   figure out a way to do something using *only* CSS. I know that there
>   is no way to do such thing with CSS so I provided a Javascript
>   solution and the OP accepted it since he was convinced there is no way to
>   handle such situation using only CSS.

Is adding the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to the question **relevant** or **irrelevant**?

Adding the tag can make my solution easy to find but it may change the meaning of the initial question since initially JS was not allowed. *(even if the OP is accepting the JS solution at the end).*

---

Another situation is when a user ask about a *CSS-only* way to create a shape and someone provide an SVG solution and the OP accepted this solution as he got convinced that it will be impossible or difficult to use CSS.

So should we add [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg) to such question?

---

**In other words**: If a user is asking to use *languageX* to achieve what he wants but at the end he's accepting a solution using *languageY*, should we then edit his question to include the needed tags?

I am not considering the cases where:

- A user is providing an **alternative way** using *languageY* but we can do the needed task with only *languageX*.
- A user is providing a solution using *languageY* (thinking that we cannot achieve it with *languageX*) but the OP **is not convinced** and will still wait to get more answers using only *languageX*.

For the above situations, I think that it's clearly irrelevant to include the new tags.

**UPDATE**

To add more clarification, I am considering the cases where *languageX* and *languageY* are very close and related. So it's not about providing a PHP solution for a C# problem, or providing a Bootstrap solution to a CSS-only problem (I know bootstrap is also CSS but it's a framework, so we should not add its tag even if we provide a solution using it as it can make the issue related to bootstrap which is not the case).

Here is more common situations I face usually:

- Providing a [bootstrap4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap4) solution where the OP is initially using [bootstrap3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap3) because the upgrade may easily fix the issue.
- Providing a [css-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid) solution to a [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) issue because [css-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid) can be more suitable than [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) in such situation.
- Providing a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) solution for a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) problem as the code may become very complex and it can be better to consider [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

<sup>By languageX/Y I don't mean only a programming language, but also frameworks, libraries, different versions of the same framework/language/library, etc</sup>

Comment: Related: [Updating a question's tags based on new answers using originally unavailable technology](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318608/updating-a-questions-tags-based-on-new-answers-using-originally-unavailable-tec). Different question but the answers cover similar ground.

Comment: @jpp I agree, didn't find this one ... by the way why using a turtle as an avatar? a sarcastic way to say that you are growing so fast :p

Comment: I just like turtles :)

Comment: Personally I might argue for not adding the tag.  If I'm coming to S.O. looking for some help with an issue, I'll search for that issue.  I'm not really filtering results by tags at that point.  Given the example in the OP, had I been searching for a solution to that issue, I wouldn't really be concerned if it did or did not include javascript, or made that apparent.  I'm simply concerned with finding a solution to my issue.  The lack of the javascript tag wouldn't stop me from viewing the question to see what solution was given.

Comment: @Taplar: But if you knew you needed a solution *without* Javascript, the presence of the JS tag would let you reject that question without reading it.  (Or you could even filter it out of your search results.)  If you don't find anything that way, though, you'd have to go back and look for questions where the OP thought it would take JS but it turned out answerers were able to solve it without.

Comment: It just my opinion that it's probably better to show users more questions related to their issue than not.  Not all users *know* what they need.  If they did, they might not be searching for an answer on Stack Overflow.  I'd rather a user have to look through a few questions from their search results than the potential of finding no previous questions at all due to their assumptions about what technologies are required to solve it.

Comment: Also somewhat related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364099/abusing-tag-edits

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to cover generally; it's a case-by-case determination. The closest I can get to a general rule would probably be:

Add a tag to the question if:

- OP mentions an openness for solutions using that language/library/framework
- OP *doesn't* mention they want to do it without that tag (obviously)
- OP accepted an answer that uses that language/library/framework.

**Definitely *do not* add tags to questions *just because someone answers with that language/library/framework***.

In your first case, yes, adding the tag *at that point* after OP has accepted a JavaScript answer is probably OK. Even if the accepted answer makes a wrong claim (for example, if you know it *is* possible in CSS), you can leave the tag because OP accepted a JavaScript solution. Another rule applies here: don't edit questions in such a way that they invalidate existing valid answers. If you were to remove a JavaScript tag to a CSS question after OP has accepted a JavaScript answer, that would (in a way) invalidate the accepted answer. You *can* still leave a comment criticizing any incorrect statement or downvote for any inaccuracies/less-than-useful content, even if OP accepts such an answer.

In your second example, the same logic would apply since OP accepted an untagged solution.

In other situations where someone asks an on-topic question on how to do something with, say, CSS, and a user provides a JavaScript solution, and OP hasn't accepted such an answer or responded... then you should downvote and *not* add such a tag, because there is no indication from OP that it's an acceptable, relevant answer, and every indication that it is not.

In situations where OP asks an on-topic, open-ended question on how to accomplish something and doesn't specify language or library constraints, people could ostensibly provide solutions in any number of ways: HTML, CSS, SVG, JavaScript, PHP... it's probably best to avoid adding those tags to the question, as you can very quickly max out the tag allotment that might counter-indicate to viewers that non-tagged solutions are not welcome.

As always, if OP asks a question where this complication might arise, but the question is Too Broad or otherwise off-topic, please vote to close the question, instead. Having the OP address the root problems of the question could well solve the issue of what tags to use. In any case, OP should know what languages or libraries are useful or usable for their scenario.

Comment: yes I agree it's case by case and it's difficult to have a generic rule. By the way, I didn't share any real example to avoid any kind of promotion of my own answers. And of course when the question is open to many different language, it sounds the too-broad situation as we need to be specific and am not considering this case ... maybe it wasn't clear enough in the question, but I was considering situation where X/Y are very close ... not the case where it's about PHP or C++ but more likely about very close language.

Comment: So it's about the cases where we deal with CSS/SVG, bootstrap 3 or 4, fontawesome 4/5, JS/jQuery ... and let's say that the CSS/JS example is  the more extreme one as they are two different langage but still in the same pool of technologie

Comment: @TemaniAfif version-specific tags should be used only when there are version-specific features being used or the versions are not compatible... e.g. [tag:python] vs [tag:python-3], or if you are using some new feature of Bootstrap 4. For CSS and JS, like I said in the answer, it depends on the timing and wording of the post. I see lots of posts tagged with CSS where the user says "I'm looking for a CSS solution but I can also use JavaScript"... it's OK to add the JS tag and give a JS answer there. Same thing if OP asks for CSS-only but then accepts a JS answer. Use the latest info from OP.

Comment: what about this case : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329546/8620333 ? .. the user keep rolling back my edit to have the flexbox tag where the question has nothing to do with flexbox. For me it's a kind of abusive behavior to fastly earn gold badges or am I wrong? it's clear that the question is a pure CSS issue and we can achieve the goal with any technique. I have used linear-gradient so I don't think I should also add the *linear-gradient* tag to the question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree the addition of the [tag:flexbox] tag there is wrong to add unless OP specifically adds it (e.g. he's looking for a flexbox solution & knows it). If you suspect a user is gaming the system in a bad way (trying to add a tag to questions where it doesn't belong), flag one of the posts for a moderator and describe your concerns. This kind of situation is a bit tricky because moderators do not typically handle "subject-matter expert" situations as a matter of policy, but there are *several* mods who have gold badges in HTML or CSS they could toss the flag to for consideration.

Comment: ok thanks, let's see if he will roll back your edit ...