# Tagging users questions answered by myself

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-score

I'm curious to know;

If I were to answer a question tagged with say [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and subsequently receive an up-vote for my answer and I then edited the question adding a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag:

- Would I receive points against the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag too?
- If so, is this practice frowned upon?

Comment: Closely related: [Tagging a question based on its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252079)

Comment: Yes, you would get javascript credit.  Editing for the sole purpose of increasing your tag score is frowned upon.  But if the tag really is important in categorizing the question, please do add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do gain and lose points towards tag badges when tags on questions change. You can also gain and lose those badges if you score goes above/below the threshold based on tag edits.

If you're just making tag edits to gain badges, then yes, that's frowned upon. If you add tags that don't apply just to get a badge, you're going to lose it anyway when the tag is removed. If you add a borderline tag (one that might appear relevant, but really isn't due to the details of the question), then that might be subject to removal too, so only add tags when you're sure they're relevant to the question.

(In your specific example, if you gave a purely jQuery answer, then retagged just to get the JavaScript badge points, that would be frowned upon. If you can provide a JavaScript answer, then the tag is relevant and can be added.)

Answer (score 3):

> Would I receive points against the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag too?

Yes.  Your tag score is based on the tags that are on the question when it is calculated.  Note that this is a double edge sword.  If a tag is removed then your tag score for that tag will go down for that tag.

> If so, is this practice frowned upon?

It depends.  If the tag belongs there then no, it is not frowned upon.  We want the question to be tagged appropriately.  On the other hand, adding tags that should not be there is frowned upon. This could get you edit banned if others notice and you do it frequently enough.